# itemForActivityType not being called

Tags: xcode, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

i just made one wrapper class for share helper my code is as follow.

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [message], applicationActivities: nil)

 activityVC.setValue(subject, forKey: "subject")
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: String!, completed:Bool, objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) in
}
fromVC.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

problem starts here, UIActivityItemSource methods not being call

```
override func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
            switch activityType
            {
            case UIActivityTypeMail:
                return msg
            case UIActivityTypeMessage:
                return msg
            case UIActivityTypePostToFacebook:
                return msg
            case UIActivityTypePostToTwitter:
                return strTwitterShare
            default:
                return msg
            }

        }
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 6):

It should work if you use let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self], applicationActivities: nil)

... then your message is provided inside your itemForActivityType method.